# how do you upload a webservice with connection tu your database for consumming since any place?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, connection, database-connection

well I need to upload or to public in internet a webservice, I need watch it in anyplace, to consum it, since any part of world, how do i do it?

where do i upload it? it has a connection with my database

my webservice is for add, for edit,delete and queries in my database.

it is going to work for two windows applications.

i have seen webpage for upload page, but they dont work for me, they are .html and not webservice

can i public it, since my computer? and consum it, if my computer is turn on, only?

for example Server is in computer A, but my application is going to be in computer B (since any place of world), other application is going to be in computer C (since any place of world), then i need they can do, queries, add, edit, delete since their computer, but server is in computer A

Comment: You need to upload it to a server. Just like any other aspect of the internet.... Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @Bazzz for example Server is in computer A, but my application is going to be in computer B (since any place of world), other application is going to be in computer C (since any place of world), then i need they can do, queries, add, edit, delete since their computer, but server is in computer A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't upload WebServices, you need to Host them.

And that means you need a Hosting Provider, or run a HTTP server on your own (always-on) Internet connection.

The kind of Host depends on your platform, for a WCF or ASP.NET service you need Windows-based hosting.

Comment: my web service is for asp.net i have made it in visual studio